# Problem: Deleted data disapear only after page refresh

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

I have a section in which users can delete some elements on my page, I am using redux with the REST API.
When a user deletes the element it does not disappear until when he/she refresh the page.

Here is my action to delete the data

```
const deleteEmailFooter = (emailID) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const response = await api.delete(`/signatures/${emailID}`);
    return dispatch({
      type: "DELETE_EMAIL_FOOTER",
      payload: id,
    });
  } catch (error) {}
};
```

Here is my reducer

```
const initialState = [];

const videoFooterReducer = (emailFooters = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "DELETE_EMAIL_FOOTER":
      return emailFooters.filter((x) => x.id !== action.payload);
    default:
      return emailFooters;
  }
};

export default videoFooterReducer
```

Here is the handle delete function

```
const handleDelete = () =>{
        dispatch(actions.videoFooterActions.deleteEmailFooter(signature.id));
}
```

What do I need to do to solve the problem?

Comment: the easiest thing would be to hide the element until the page gets refreshed. This is probably easier than doing a window.location.reload to force a page refresh

Comment: @tstrand66 my question what is the problem here? why does not remove the element in dom until refresh?

Comment: check if "catch" not happen there. Also i see 'payload' in your action but not 'id'

Comment: no catch erro the data is successfully deleted but data in dom still there until I refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing here but in `emailFooters.filter((x) => x.id !== action.id)` is probably not matching `x.id !== action.id` You could try `String(x.id) !== String(action.id)` or maybe the action does not have the correct data, try to console.log the action or better yet; use redux devtools and see what the action is and how it changed the state.

Here is how I would log (if devtools is not an option)

```
console.log('action is:',JSON.stringify(action));
emailFooters.filter((x) => {
  console.log('comparing:',x.id,'with:'action.id')
  console.log(
    'type of id:',
    typeof x.id,
    'typeof action id:',
    typeof action.id
  )
  return x.id !== action.id
})
```

Comment: solved the problem, it was how I get the data to display them on my page

Comment: @TheDeadMan `Uncaught (in promise) {type: 'DELETE_EMAIL_FAILED' ...` this suggests that the reducer is throwing an error maybe log the error in the catch will give you some more information. It suggest that some of the emailFooters are null or undefined and doing `x.id` would be `undefined.id`, that will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to redirect from your controller file where you handle all your server side apis. for example in your case just redirect like `response.redirect('/signatures')`.